# Is there a right way in Wordpress to undo enforcement of a single link color?

Tags: wordpress, user-experience, usability

Ok, stupid question here.

Making visited and unvisited links look different has been a "Top 10 Mistakes in Web Design" issue from when Jakob Nielsen's name was a fashionable name to drop.

Wordpress's "twentysixteen" theme at least, and perhaps baked into Wordpress, is the choice of which **one** color links will have. Following the usability guideline is not possible with that choice.

What are the better ways to address issues like this? Rename a copy of twentysixteen and go through the CSS and delete all assignment of colors to `link` and `vlink` in CSS? Install a UX sanity plugin?

Comment: I have similar wishes with regard to fonts... the theme has a serif font for main body text for onscreen reading...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then you probably looking for [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner, thank you; could you restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provided nice feature when you want to change **Template** or **CSS** without altering anything in core files and Wordpress calls it **[Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)**.

When you create child theme, you will able to modify almost everything without any worry and achieve your desired result. Documentation for Child theme is also pretty straight forward so you will able to create child theme easily.

Let me know if you have any doubts.